# Simplify root inside of root

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
xxx=(2 Sqrt[1 - 2/(1 + Sqrt[G1])] G1 + 
 2 Sqrt[((-1 + Sqrt[G1]) G1)/(1 + Sqrt[G1])])/(-1 + 2 G1)
```

I have quite complicated expression. I want to simplify little better. I tried

```
FullSimplify[xxx, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand},
  Assumptions -> {G1 > 1}]
```

You can see that is can be simplified to by hand

```
(2 Sqrt[-1 + G1] Sqrt[G1])/(-1 + 2 G1)
```

however, it does not work in this case. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weirdly, the *less* specific assumption $G1>0$ works to achieve your simplification here:

```
Simplify[xxx, Assumptions -> G1 > 0]
```

[image: simpler result, as requested]

Comment: It is very strange, but it helps a lot! thank you

Answer (score 0):

An other way is avoiding square roots.

```
FullSimplify[xxx /. G1 -> g2^2, Assumptions -> g2 > 1] /. 
      g2 -> Sqrt[G1]
```

[image]